# Time Machiine Volumes owned by root

Tags: macos, operating-systems, finder

I recently set up time machine to back up to two external USB drives. backups are proceeding fine, but the drives are owned by root and I can't access them via "enter time machine" or via normal finder. I'm forced to either start a root finder or use terminal/sudo.

How can I fix this, chmod of /Volumes/drive(s) didn't work. Becoming root and changing permissions to r/w for everyone didn’t work. I’m using Yosemite.

Comment: I really am not any kind of nix perms guru, but did you just try Get Info & setting... me full perms, my group full perms, everyone, read only. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed.  I went back to the command-line and did sudo su. Then did a chown me, chmod 777 on the each backup drive. Then I cd'd into each drive and chowned Backups.backupdb as me (my uid). It all stuck after a reboot and TM is working fine. Hope this helps someone, sorry for answering my own question.